# how to write class with data members and member function c++

Tags: visual-c++

hi guys i would like u to help me in my assignment i had try to solve it but there are some of the things that making me :s i knw how to creat the name and id

string Name;
int Id;

bt wt does it mean a **pointer to a dynamically allocated array of grades:s:s:S?** 
i jst knw how to declare a pointer like : double* Grades;

here is the assignment......

Create a Class StudentGrades with the following Data members:

- Name : type String
- Id: type integer
- Grades: a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of Grades. Type is: pointer to double (* double)

It includes the following member functions:

- A No-argument Constructor
- A Constructor that takes two arguments : a String and an Integer and initializes the Name with the String and the ID with the Integer.
- Set and get functions for Name, ID
- A print function for Student information. It prints name, Id and the grades.
- An overloaded Assignment operator of the Class Objects
- A Copy Constructor of the Class Objects
- Use the Syntax for the copy constructor and the overloaded assignment operator.

In another file create a C++ program that prompts the user for data to create four objects of the class StudentGrades. The first object (std1) has 5 grades, and the second (std2) has 6 grades and the third (std3) has 4 grades  and fourth (std4) has no grades and data. 
Then copy std2 into std4 and assign std1 to std3. Then print the details of the four objects

hey i solved my assignment bt iam trying to running it bt it doesn't work can any body please tell me where the problem is n the program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class student_grades{
private:
    string name,n;
    int Id,i;
    double* grades[];

public:
    student_grades();

    student_grades(sting, int);

    student_grades(const student_grades&);

    void set(string name,int Id){
        cout << "enter the name and the ID";
        cin >> n >> i;
        n = name;
        i = Id;
    }

    void get(){
        return i;
        return n;
    }

    void student_grades (student_grades&opr){
        name = name.opr;
        Id = Id.opr;
        grades[] = grades[].opr;
    }

    void student_info(){
        cout << "the name of the student is:" << name;
        cout << "the id for the srudent is:" << Id;
        grades = new double[];
        cout << "the grades of the student is:" << grades[] << endl;
        delete []grades;
    }

};

student_grades::student_grades() {}

student_grades::student_grades(string name, int Id) {
    name=" ";
    Id=0;
}

student_grades::student_grades(const student_grades& copy) {
    name=copy.name;
    Id=copy.Id;
}

int main() {

    student_grades std1;
    std1.set();
    cin >> std1.grades[5];
    std1.get();

    student_grades std2;
    std2.set();
    cin >> std2.grades[6];
    std2.get();

    student_grades std3;
    std3.set();
    cin >> std3.grades[4];
    std3.get();

    student_grades std4;
    std4.set();
    cin >> std4.grades[];
    std4.get();

    std1 = std3;
    std2 = std4;

    cout << std1 << std2 << std3 << std4;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamically allocated array is an array that isn't given a specific size until run time, unlike a fixed array declaration is at compile time. A declaration of a *fixed* array looks like:

```
int grades[500];
```

That array will allocate memory for 500 integers and stay that way unless you destroy it or resize it.

Creating a dynamically allocated array would look more like this:

```
int* grades = NULL; // A declaration in your StudentGrades class
int n = <get size from somewhere>; // Makes the size "dynamic"
grades = new int[n]; // This definition could be in your StudentGrades ctor,
                     // with n being a parameter.
```

Then you could continue by initializing all of the array elements to 0 or fill up your array with other values as needed. When you're done with the array, clean it up. This could be in your destructor:

```
delete [] grades;
grades = NULL;
```

Comment: thank you soo much this was really helpfull bt can i ask more qs??

Comment: Yes, you can ask more questions, but I will not do your homework for you.

Comment: LOL no offcoures u wont do it iam jst confusing abt things dont worry
how we can print a function we didnt take the input from the user for it?

Comment: Ok... to ask additional questions, don't post new ones, just edit your original post.